# Find image in a complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider map $z \to w=f(z)= \sqrt{z} $ $\sqrt{1}=1$; and compute the image f(D) of $D = \{z:1/\sqrt{3}|Im(z)|<Re(z)<1\} $

I know that $f: D \to f(D)$ is bijective

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the best I could do using *Wolfram Mathematica*.

Hope it can be useful
[image]